# Как удалить слова в строках с помощью Remove

Tags: c#

string slovo = Console.ReadLine();

```
        Console.WriteLine(slovo.Split(' ').Length);

        string slovo2= slovo.Split(' ').Last();

        string slovo1 = slovo.Split()[0];

        slovo = slovo.Trim();

        string text = slovo.Remove(slovo1, slovo2);

        Console.WriteLine( text );
```

slovo1 переднее слово в строке

slovo2 заднее слово в строку.
Вопрос: В как удалить slovo1 и slovo2 если это string, а не int?

Comment: `string.Replace`?

Comment: нет slovo.Remove

Answer (score 1):

Ремув просто удаляет подстроку начиная с определенного индекса. То есть что бы удалить слово в конце строки нужно написать индекс с которого начинается это слово:

```
    // ... семистрочная строка
    string test1 = "0123456";

    // ... Начать удаление с 4го символа включительно
    string result1 = test1.Remove(3);

    // ... Показать "012"
    Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

Но лучше использовать риплейс

slovo.Replace("ЗамениМеня", "");